# Most interoperable web service platform for Apache Tomcat JSP platform to be consumed by .NET

Tags: java, .net, web-services, jsp, tomcat

For a company that has their stack built on Apache Tomcat and JSP what would be the best web service platform to be leveraged by that infrastructure that would be consumed by .NET client.

From the .NET side I know the answer would be Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) but I'm not sure from the other side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAX-WS. [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) is a good implementation. [JAX-WS RI](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) as well.

These don't require an application server to run. Both can be run on tomcat ([RI example](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2007/07/running_jaxws_s.html))